# How can I display my quiz results by majority of answers chosen?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The idea of this quiz is to show which character you'd be in a game depending on how you answer the questions. So far the code keeps track of the users choice but I am having issues processes the data.

I want the code to show what character the user will be after the data is processed by displaying the character with the most points based on the users choices.

Here is the sample code:

```js
// Create a listener for clicks on the 'start the quiz' button on the front page. 
document.getElementById("beginquiz").addEventListener("click", startQuiz);

// When the button is clicked the 'intro' div is hidden and the first question div is displayed
function startQuiz() {
  document.getElementById("intro").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("q1").style.display = "block";
}

// Create an array object to store all the quiz answers. Each selected answer should increase the category score by 1. The highest score will be the personality 'type' in the results. 
const answerData = { // one object, with names as keys, scores as values
  Warlock: 0,
  Hunter: 0,
  Titan: 0
};

// Get all of the .buttons elements
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
// Add an onclick event listener to every element with a class of .buttons
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  // When an element with .buttons is clicked, run the function called buttonClicked
  buttons[i].onclick = buttonClicked;
}

// Define what buttonClicked does
function buttonClicked(e) {
  var target = e.target; // 1. `this` is parent, need target
  console.log(target);
  // Get the current element's data-score value
  var selectedType = target.dataset.score; // 2. score is the value
  // Increase the selected answer's 'type' by 1
  console.log(selectedType);
  answerData[selectedType]++; // 4. after change of structure
  // Hide the current question div
  this.parentElement.style.display = "none";
  // Work out what the next question div is
  var nextQuestion = this.parentElement.dataset.next;
  // Display the next question element
  document.getElementById(nextQuestion).style.display = "block";
}

function endQuiz() {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = `${answerData}`;

}
```

```css
.question,
#result {
  display: none;
}

.button li {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.button li:hover {
  color: #bfbfbf;
  background-color: #555;
}

#intro,
.question,
#result {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#beginquiz {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  width: 20em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#beginquiz:hover {
  color: #bfbfbf;
  background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="intro">
    <h2>Destiny Quiz.</h2>
    <button id="beginquiz">Start the quiz</button>
  </div>

  <div class="question" id="q1" data-next="q2">
    <h2>Question 1:</h2>
    <p>How would you prefer to get around? </p>
    <ol class="button">
      <li data-score="Hunter">Double Jump</li>
      <li data-score="Warlock">Float</li>
      <li data-score="Titan">Jetpack</li>
    </ol>
  </div>

  <div class="question" id="q2" data-next="q3">
    <h2>Question 2:</h2>
    <p>What ability would you choose? </p>
    <ol class="button">
      <li data-score="Titan">Barricade</li>
      <li data-score="Warlock">Rift</li>
      <li data-score="Hunter">Dodge</li>
    </ol>
  </div>

  <div class="question" id="q3" data-next="q4">
    <h2>Question 3:</h2>
    <p>What title appeals to you?</p>
    <ol class="button">
      <li data-score="Warlock">Space magician </li>
      <li data-score="Titan">Absolute tank/unit</li>
      <li data-score="Hunter">Stealth gunslinger</li>
    </ol>
  </div>

  <div class="question" id="q4" data-next="q5">
    <h2>Question 4:</h2>
    <p>Arc What super/alt sounds interesting to you?</p>
    <ol class="button">
      <li data-score="Hunter">Staff wielder</li>
      <li data-score="Titan">Thunder fists</li>
      <li data-score="Warlock">Electric beam/fingers</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div class="question" id="q5" data-next="q6">
    <h2>Question 5:</h2>
    <p>Solar What super/alt sounds interesting to you?</p>
    <ol class="button">
      <li data-score="Titan">Hammer time</li>
      <li data-score="Warlock">Flame blade</li>
      <li data-score="Hunter">Golden gun</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div class="question" id="q6" data-next="q7">
    <h2>Question 6:</h2>
    <p>Void What super/alt sounds interesting to you?</p>
    <ol class="button">
      <li data-score="Warlock">Space energy ball</li>
      <li data-score="Hunter">Elusive archer</li>
      <li data-score="Titan">Shield defence</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div class="question" id="q7" data-next="q8">
    <h2>Question 7:</h2>
    <p>Melee preference?</p>
    <ol class="button">
      <li data-score="Titan">Punchy boi</li>
      <li data-score="Hunter">Knife to meet you</li>
      <li data-score="Warlock">open palm slap</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div class="question" id="q8" data-next="result">
    <h2>Question 8:</h2>
    <p>What play style appeals to you?</p>
    <ol class="button">
      <li data-score="Titan">Tank</li>
      <li data-score="Hunter">Mobility</li>
      <li data-score="Hunter">Ability</li>
    </ol>
  </div>

  <div id="result">
    <h2>Class Results</h2>
  </div>
  <script src="/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Would like to show character chosen and an image if possible. Could this be done with and if/else statement or maybe a math.max? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: _"Create an array object to store..."_ — you are creating an object, which is _not_ an array. An object's attribute can be accessed using `[]` but that doesn't make it an array, it's just an alternative syntax to the 'dot', a syntax that can be used with variables; `obj.member` and `obj['member']` are equivalent, but you can write `obj[myvar]` while you _can't_ do `obj.myvar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there could be a tie, I decided to employ the reduce function and manage it through there. It looks beastly, but here it is commented:

```
let myTypes = 
   Object.keys( // in the end we want an array of Types
      Object.fromEntries( // we need to convert the array (entries) back into an object
         Object.entries(answerData) // object.entries turns answer data into an iterable array
           .reduce((b, a) => { //reduce - b is our accumlating value, a is the iterable
              if (b.length === 0) return [a] // if we're just starting, put the first type in there
              let bb = b[0];
              if (+a[1] > +bb[1]) b = [a]; // otherwise look at the next type and if the score is larger than the one we already have, replace it
              else if (+a[1] === +bb[1]) b.push(a) // but if it's a tie, add to it
              return b;
      }, []))) // all the closing tags
```

I put it all in a testable snippet, and triggered the `endQuiz()` function at the end og `buttonClicked()`:

```
if (nextQuestion === 'result') endQuiz()
```

```js
document.getElementById("beginquiz").addEventListener("click", startQuiz);

// When the button is clicked the 'intro' div is hidden and the first question div is displayed
function startQuiz() {
  document.getElementById("intro").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("q1").style.display = "block";
}

// Create an array object to store all the quiz answers. Each selected answer should increase the category score by 1. The highest score will be the personality 'type' in the results. 
const answerData = { // one object, with names as keys, scores as values
  Warlock: 0,
  Hunter: 0,
  Titan: 0
};

// Get all of the .buttons elements
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
// Add an onclick event listener to every element with a class of .buttons
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  // When an element with .buttons is clicked, run the function called buttonClicked
  buttons[i].onclick = buttonClicked;
}

// Define what buttonClicked does
function buttonClicked(e) {
  var target = e.target; // 1. `this` is parent, need target
 // console.log(target);
  // Get the current element's data-score value
  var selectedType = target.dataset.score; // 2. score is the value
  // Increase the selected answer's 'type' by 1
 // console.log(selectedType);
  answerData[selectedType]++; // 4. after change of structure
  // Hide the current question div
  this.parentElement.style.display = "none";
  // Work out what the next question div is
  var nextQuestion = this.parentElement.dataset.next;
  // Display the next question element
  document.getElementById(nextQuestion).style.display = "block";
  if (nextQuestion === 'result') endQuiz()
}

function endQuiz() {

  let myTypes = Object.keys(Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(answerData).reduce((b, a) => {
    if (b.length === 0) return [a]
    let bb = b[0];
    if (+a[1] > +bb[1]) b = [a];
    else if (+a[1] === +bb[1]) b.push(a)
    return b;
  }, [])))
  let result = ''
  if (myTypes.length === 1) result = 'You are a ' + myTypes[0];
  else result = 'You could either be a ' + myTypes.join(' or a');
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;

}
```

```css
.question,
#result {
  display: none;
}

.button li {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.button li:hover {
  color: #bfbfbf;
  background-color: #555;
}

#intro,
.question,
#result {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#beginquiz {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  width: 20em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#beginquiz:hover {
  color: #bfbfbf;
  background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<div id="intro">
  <h2>Destiny Quiz.</h2>
  <button id="beginquiz">Start the quiz</button>
</div>

<div class="question" id="q1" data-next="q2">
  <h2>Question 1:</h2>
  <p>How would you prefer to get around? </p>
  <ol class="button">
    <li data-score="Hunter">Double Jump</li>
    <li data-score="Warlock">Float</li>
    <li data-score="Titan">Jetpack</li>
  </ol>
</div>

<div class="question" id="q2" data-next="q3">
  <h2>Question 2:</h2>
  <p>What ability would you choose? </p>
  <ol class="button">
    <li data-score="Titan">Barricade</li>
    <li data-score="Warlock">Rift</li>
    <li data-score="Hunter">Dodge</li>
  </ol>
</div>

<div class="question" id="q3" data-next="q4">
  <h2>Question 3:</h2>
  <p>What title appeals to you?</p>
  <ol class="button">
    <li data-score="Warlock">Space magician </li>
    <li data-score="Titan">Absolute tank/unit</li>
    <li data-score="Hunter">Stealth gunslinger</li>
  </ol>
</div>

<div class="question" id="q4" data-next="q5">
  <h2>Question 4:</h2>
  <p>Arc What super/alt sounds interesting to you?</p>
  <ol class="button">
    <li data-score="Hunter">Staff wielder</li>
    <li data-score="Titan">Thunder fists</li>
    <li data-score="Warlock">Electric beam/fingers</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div class="question" id="q5" data-next="q6">
  <h2>Question 5:</h2>
  <p>Solar What super/alt sounds interesting to you?</p>
  <ol class="button">
    <li data-score="Titan">Hammer time</li>
    <li data-score="Warlock">Flame blade</li>
    <li data-score="Hunter">Golden gun</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div class="question" id="q6" data-next="q7">
  <h2>Question 6:</h2>
  <p>Void What super/alt sounds interesting to you?</p>
  <ol class="button">
    <li data-score="Warlock">Space energy ball</li>
    <li data-score="Hunter">Elusive archer</li>
    <li data-score="Titan">Shield defence</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div class="question" id="q7" data-next="q8">
  <h2>Question 7:</h2>
  <p>Melee preference?</p>
  <ol class="button">
    <li data-score="Titan">Punchy boi</li>
    <li data-score="Hunter">Knife to meet you</li>
    <li data-score="Warlock">open palm slap</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div class="question" id="q8" data-next="result">
  <h2>Question 8:</h2>
  <p>What play style appeals to you?</p>
  <ol class="button">
    <li data-score="Titan">Tank</li>
    <li data-score="Hunter">Mobility</li>
    <li data-score="Hunter">Ability</li>
  </ol>
</div>

<div id="result">
  <h2>Class Results</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect! Still have some things to sort out but this makes everything function. Going to look into adding images when the respective character gets chosen and a restart quiz function. Thanks Kinglish I appreciate the response, you saved me hours of tinkering!

Comment: If you have any ideas on how I can get the ball rolling that would be awesome!

Comment: The easiest thing would be to name your images the same as the character. Titan.jpg.. then just write that to the page.